# Trying to fill table with default value

Tags: sql, sql-server, default-value

I have 2 tables, Suppliers, and Products. I'm trying to fill them with random info.
Table Products, Column supplier_id. I set this column `default` value to **-1**.

I'm getting error on the line where I'm trying to insert default value in given column.
Check the code below, error msg at the bottom of the post.

SUPPLIERS:

```
CREATE TABLE Suppliers
(
 id int primary key identity(1,1),
 "name" nvarchar(50) not null,
 telephone nvarchar(50) default 'N/A',
 "address" nvarchar(50) default 'N/A'

)
INSERT INTO Suppliers (name,telephone,address)
values ('Supplier 1', '021-555-333', 'Jovana Petrovica 72, Beograd 11000'),
        ('Supplier 2', '021-555-333', 'Branka Radicevica 13, Zrenjanin 23000'),
        ('Supplier 3', '021-555-333', 'Bulevar Oslobodjenja 30A, Novi Sad 21000')
```

PRODUCTS:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
 id int primary key identity(1,1),
 "name" nvarchar(50) not null,
   price float default 0,
  supplier_id int default -1,
  foreign key (supplier_id) references Suppliers(id) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT 

)
INSERT INTO Products (name, price, supplier_id)
values ('Product 1', 800, 3),
        ('Product 2', 1300, 1),
        ('Product 3', 230, 2),
        ('Product 4', 570, 3),
        ('Product 5', 1225, 2);
INSERT INTO Products (name, price)
values ('Product 6', 80); // I read online this is the way to insert default values (?)
```

Error msg:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Products__suppli__03F0984C". The conflict occurred in database "Tehna", table "dbo.Suppliers", column 'id'.
> The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You can't insert supplier_id -1 into Products, since there is no supplier_id -1 in the Products table, so the foreign key constraint rejects it.

Comment: It simply says you default value is not correct according yo the foreign key defined, maybe set the default to `NULL` ?

Comment: please tag your DBMS along with `sql` tag

Comment: @jarlh I just figured it out few secs ago lol. I read online NULL value in DB is not suggested. But i guess with foreign key the only option is NULL here, right?

Comment: @Luuk Yes. My bad.  I read online NULL value in DB is not suggested. But i guess with foreign key the only option is NULL here, right?

Comment: Please provide link for "I read online NULL value in DB is not suggested" . But if you need it, then why not use it?

Comment: @Luuk I dont really recall the website, maybe i misread but they were definitely mentioning something about NULLs not being the best option in some forms of use.
Question, in VisualStudio C# how do i make if statement including the NULL field from DB. Is it likr this: if(reader["supplier_id'] == **DBNull.Value**) ?

Comment: Don't believe everything you read on the Internet. NULL values serve a purpose.

Comment: @Jarlh How do i refer to a NULL value from DB using Visual Studio C#.
I need an if statement. Do i do something like this:  if(reader["supplier_id'] == **DBNull.Value**) ?

Answer (score -1):

I guess that default 'supplier_id' should be greater than 0 or null, because it's related to 'id' in Suppliers which is primary key and also an integer